# Can I create a dir/file via a shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny

In R, I can use `dir.create()` function to create a dir or `write.csv()` function to write a data table. Is it possible to do the same things in a shiny app (instead of use the download button)?

Comment: Where do you want to create this directory/file - on the user's computer, or on the server?  A function like dir.create() would create a folder on the server - probably not your desired behavior.

Comment: on the user's computer; because I almost use shiny app standalone without deployment.

Comment: If you are using standalone, then `dir.create()` should create a folder in the current working directory. You can also mention the path by `dir.create(file.path("path"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. See:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  h1('my app')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  fdir <- "BBB"
  dir.create(fdir)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```